# How to make common connection string for all DAL(Data Access Layer)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0, connection-string

I have to use "IConfiguration" for ConnectionString in my all controller.
And I also have to send it in my DAL.

I want to make a common DAL(data access layer) and inherit it in other DAL.

> > > Actually I don't want to use EF(entity framework)

```
 public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public UserController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.configuration = config;
            ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        public IActionResult ViewProfile()
        {
            UserControllerGateway userControllerGateway = new UserControllerGateway();

            UserProfileModel userProfile = new UserProfileModel();
            userProfile = userControllerGateway.ViewProfile(ConnectionString);//I have to send connectionString to my DAL

            return View(userProfile);
        }
```

```
///DAL
public class CommonGateway
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
        public SqlCommand Command { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public SqlDataReader Reader { get; set; }

        public CommonGateway()
        {
            ConnectionString = " "; //What can I do here
        }                 
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just directly use and access the IConfiguration abstraction in the DAL or in the base class of your DAL's?

Comment: Indeed, the configuration functionality is already available in .NET Core. There's no need to add yet another abstraction. As for `CommonGateway` it looks like a bug that will keep connections open longer than needed, thus harming performance and increasing delays due to blocking. A data access service class should create connections only where needed and close them as quickly as possible. Connections should have scope greater than the method they are used in

Comment: It's the data access service class that should be injected in the controllers, not the connection string. The data class could have a dependency on `IConfiguration`. Another option is to use a factory method during registration that reads the connection string and passes it as a parameter to the class's constructor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Looks like a typo  "Connections should **not** have scope greater than the method they are used in"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking how to use externalized configuration without actually externalizing it. In case the logic (or lack thereof) of that statement is not apparent, what you're wanting is not possible.

The way to share *anything* between various classes and/or projects is a class, most likely in a class library. If you like you can create a static "constants" class to hold your connection string:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "foo";
}
```

However, this is what's referred to as an "anti-pattern". In other words, it's something you should not do. In particular with something like a connection string, that tends to need to vary by environment, which is hard to achieve with a static class like this. You also have the issue of protecting this string, since your app could easily be decompiled to reveal it, along with the user name and password to access your database. If you're thinking `SecureString`, that won't work here. The original string literal is still vulnerable, even if you attempt to craft a `SecureString` out of it.

In short, externalized config is externalized for a reason. It allows you app to be provided with information it needs without tightly coupling that information to your application. You can switch it out at will, and importantly, use secure storage mechanisms to protect the information at rest.

More to the point, something like a DAL is *supposed* to be abstract. Even though you're typically creating it for a particular application, it should have a degree of reusability. If you tie the connection string to it, then it is then tightly coupled to that particular domain, which is usually a bad design.

Long and short, keep the config where it belongs: at the application level and externalized.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a static class and use it to access your DAL implementation easily where you need it.

Comment: This should be a comment. In any case it's a bad idea that's *fixed* by using dependency injection. Static classes make it *harder* to use or test a service